# Can't get UILabel's text to stay on multiple lines

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UILabel that should display text on multiple lines in case that it's too long to stay on a single line. This how I set its parameters in interface builder:

[image]

But even by doing so, the text still gets truncated:

[image]

This is how I set the text at runtime:

```
    let text = "left button pressed 5 seconds ago, you may want to press another button now"
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(statusLabel.font.pointSize), range: (text as NSString).rangeOfString("left"))

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
    statusLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Like you see I even tried to add a paragraph style attribute to force the text to stay on multiple lines, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you're setting the auto layout constraints so you have the top, leading and trailing spaces defined, but don't hookup a vertical height, the label will adjust itself based on the content.

Edit:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had a vertical height constraint equal to 50. I removed it but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Ok it was that I forgot to add the leading and trailing space constraints, it works now.